# Java - make relation between Object list and Hashtable?

Tags: java, list, hashtable, relationship

Is it possible in java to make a relation between Object list and Hashtable.

For example I have this code:

```
//For list
MyClass1 obj1 = new MyClass1();
MyClass2 obj2 = new MyClass2();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj1);
list.add(obj2);

//For Hashtable
int first = 10;
String second = "something";
Hashtable<String, Object> hash = new ArrayList<>();
hash.put("1st", first);
hash.put("2nd", second);
```

Now how can make relations like that:

`list.get(0)` would be related with hash record => `{"1st", first}` and

`list.get(1)` would be related with hash record => `{"2nd", second}`?
So for example later if I would got `list`, I could see that it's related with specific hash record?

P.S. I tried approach like this:

```
List<Hashtable<Object, Hashtable<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But then I figured, that my key in first Hashtable sometimes could be the same, what I mean for example there could be such relations:

```
obj1 related with {"1st", first}
```

and then

```
MyClass1 obj3 = new MyClass1();
obj3 related with {"2nd", second}
```

So then I would have the same key for another record, so it overwrite the old one (and also I have overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods, to be able to use objects as keys, but this one gives the problem as for this reason I can't use it as keys as these keys would be treated as the same).

**Update:**

To make it more clear.
For example I have created two same objects (relatively speaking).

```
MyClass1 obj1 = new MyClass1("name");
MyClass1 obj2 = new MyClass1("name");
```

Now I need one object to be related with one Hashtable record, the other object with another Hashtable record.
So if I use something "obj1 show me Hashtable record you have relation with", and it would return Hashtable record it was related (as showed above). And I have a problem relating these objects using maps, because these objects have same parameters (so in Hashtable, these keys would be treated as the same key and would overwrite the other?).

I figured I could do something like this:

```
List<List<Object>> final_list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
Hashtable<String, Object> myHash = new Hashtable<String, Object>
```

So then:

```
myHash.add("1", "something");
myHash.add("2", 10);
row.add(obj1);
row.add(myHash);
final_lit.add(row);
```

This one kinda works, but it does not really look good as I need to treat first value from list as special, because it is one kind of Object and the rest are Hashtables.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.

So if you create a new `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

You should be able to retrieve the keys in order like this:

```
Object[] keys = myMap.keySet().toArray();
Object firstItem = myMap.get(keys[0]);
```

Concrete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        myMap.put("1", "item 1");
        myMap.put("3", "item 2");
        myMap.put("4", "item 3");
        myMap.put("2", "item 4");

        Object[] keys = myMap.keySet().toArray();

        for(Object key : keys){
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + "; Value: " + myMap.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Key: 1; Value: item 1
Key: 3; Value: item 2
Key: 4; Value: item 3
Key: 2; Value: item 4
```

Comment: In order not to have to generate a full array just to get the first key (or first few keys), you can use `myMap.keySet().iterator().next()` instead.

Comment: Maybe I don't understood something, but it looks like it uses same keys as would be defined in normal `map`. But for my problem I wanted something like: map record references list value. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: "map record references list value" this bears no meaning. If my answer isn't what you're looking for you have to rephrase your problem in a way that we can actually understand it. Don't give any incorrect code samples of what you want to do, just state in a few lines what you want to accomplish.